# Calculate the limit of spherical cap in spherical coordinate

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

I am using spherical coordinate system $r,\theta, \phi$ like this picture.[image]

Consider I have a sphere with radius $R$, is divided into two hemisphere $S$ and $P$.[image]

With this given information I am able to calculate $\phi$ limits for $P$ portion over $T$ using the following method:

$$
\begin{split}
\tan \beta = z/y,\\
 z=R\cos\theta,
\end{split}\quad \iff \quad y={R\cos\theta\over\tan\beta}
$$

$$
\begin{split}
R\sin\theta\sin\phi={R\cos\theta\over\tan\beta}, \\
\sin\phi={1\over\tan\beta\tan\theta},
\end{split}\quad \iff \quad
\phi=\arcsin{1\over\tan\beta\tan\theta}.$$
So the $\phi$ can go until $\pi -\phi$.

Now consider my $P$ is not a hemisphere: rather it is a spherical cap, where the cap size can be defined by an angle $\gamma$.

[image]

What will be my $\phi$ in this case to calculate the $P$ portion over the line $T$?