# Calulate area when two circle intersect each other

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, noneuclidean-geometry

I have Sphere with radius R. Inside the sphere I have Two circle. One circle is fixed defined by $\alpha$. Another circle can rotate and the orientation of that circle can be defined by $\beta$. From the centre of the sphere until the edge of the movable circle create $\alpha$ angle with $z$ axis. $h$ and $a$ are distance from the origin and base radius of this circle .[image]

Now when both circle intersect each other what will be the surface area of intersection? Using spherical coordinate system $r,\theta,\phi$, I know that my $\theta $ limit goes from $\gamma$ to $\alpha$. But I am not getting the limit for $\phi$ with this given parameters. I am trying to calculate the intersected surface area using only calculus and trigonometry for relevancy of my future problem.

Comment: @YuriyS I have edited the picture. Is it clear now?

Comment: To the edited version: you mean the area of a circular segment on the horizontal circle which is cut off by the inclined circle?

Comment: Or the part of the sphere surface cut off by the two circles? This seems more likely

Comment: @YuriyS It is the whole surface area in between two circle's intersection.

Comment: Yeah part of the sphere cut off by two circle.

Comment: I see. Nice question. I'll think about it, but 3D geometry is not my forte

Comment: @YuriyS Sure. Ideally 3D make things more complicated.

Comment: When you asked this same question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3245142/area-of-a-spherical-cap-crossing-an-intersection and again in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3266161/area-of-a-spherical-cap-across-an-intersection, both times is was marked as a duplicate thereby referring you to several useful answers to your question. If those answers did not solve your problem, I would suggest you edit this question to refer to those answers and explain why you cannot use them. It might lead to a resolution for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll change the problem statement a little so I can use Cartesian coordinates at first.

Also let $R=1$, since we can always multiply the answer by $R^2$.

Let Circle 1 lie in the horizontal plane with elevation $d$ (Plane 1).

Let Circle 2 lie in the plane defined by the radius vector $\vec{h}$ (Plane 2).

Equation of Plane 1:

$$z=d$$

Equation of Plane 2:

$$h_x x+h_y y+h_z z=h^2$$

Equation of the sphere:

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$

Now we transition to spherical coordinates:

$$x = r \sin \theta \cos \phi$$

$$y = r \sin \theta \sin \phi$$

$$z = r \cos \theta$$

Which gives us:

$$r=1$$

> $$\cos \theta=d$$
>
> $$h_x \sin \theta \cos \phi+h_y \sin \theta \sin \phi+h_z \cos \theta=h^2$$

We now have equations to determine the intersection points of the two circles on the sphere.

$$\pm \sqrt{1-d^2}(h_x  \cos \phi+h_y \sin \phi)+h_z d=h^2$$

> $$h_x  \cos \phi+h_y \sin \phi= \pm\frac{h^2-h_z d}{\sqrt{1-d^2}}$$

Define:

$$h_x=\cos \delta, \qquad h_y= \sin \delta$$

Then we have:

$$\cos (\phi-\delta)=\pm\frac{h^2-h_z d}{\sqrt{1-d^2}}$$

$$\phi= \delta+\arccos \left(\pm \frac{h^2-h_z d}{\sqrt{1-d^2}} \right)$$

> $$\phi= \arccos h_x+\arccos\left(\pm  \frac{h^2-h_z d}{\sqrt{1-d^2}} \right)$$
>
> $$\theta=\arccos d$$

We found the intersection point coordinates (note also the condition for their existence):

$$-1 \leq \frac{h^2-h_z d}{\sqrt{1-d^2}} \leq 1$$

I think now half of the problem is solved, since we can use those points to set up the limits of integration on the surface of the sphere.

Comment: Thanks for your great try...So for the $\phi$ another limit suppose to be $\pi-\phi$ right?

Comment: @T.an, not exactly, see my edit. I forgot that I have two solutions for $\sin \theta$

Comment: so one is for when circle goes up from right side and crossing each other and another is for left side when it makes reverse crossing?

Comment: @T.an, you make my head hurt with this question :). I'm better at algebra than geometry, so I hope you figure it out

Comment: what should be the value of $h_z$? Actually $h$ is the height from origin to the circle. Also how can $\beta $ will effect the orientation? any idea?

Comment: @T.an, going by your picture, $h$ is the *distance* from the origin to the second circle. As for the angle $\beta$, it has to relate to the direction of the vector $\vec{h}$ in some way. I'm not sure exactly

Comment: @T.an, **important**: my $\gamma$ is not the same as yours. I will edit

Comment: actually this problem come from a previous problem which was much simpler. you can have a look for a much clear idea. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301890/calculate-the-limit-of-spherical-cap-in-spherical-coordinate